# response view with v-component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

How can i load the v-component and v-component2 ?

1) in vue component 1

```
watch: {
    loader () {
        axios.post("/laravel_route", {
             param: value
        })
        .then (response => {
            $("#section").hmtl(response.data);
        })
    }
}
```

2) In controller of Laravel

```
public function laravel_route(Request $request){
    return view('anotherview', compact("request"));
}
```

3) In the another.view.blade.php

```
<v-component>
    <v-component2></v-component2>
</v-component>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can render components via ajax.